# Why the error ORA-04098 is raised?

Tags: oracle, triggers, ora-04098

I try to run the following trigger code on Oracle 11g:

```
create trigger attempt
  before insert on orde
  for each row
begin
  if(:new.supplierid < 10) or (:new.supplierid > 99) then

    dbms_output.put_line('SUPPLIERID SHOULD BE BETWEEN 11 AND 99');

  end if;
end;
```

It successfully creates the trigger, but when inserting any values into the table `orde`, it generates the following error:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'GOOGLE.ATTEMPT' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Why this error is raised?

Comment: compile and run "show errors" from sqlplus

Comment: Don't use a trigger for this.  Use a `check` constraint.

Comment: The trigger would not prevent inserting such a value - even if it was compiled successfully